# Cobalt 17.180626 debug build Ubuntu 16.04 failing to load video

Tags: launch, cobalt

When loading a Youtube video on linux-x64x11 version of cobalt, Cobalt crashes. I am able to load the front page, see the thumbnails and search, however, upon clicking a video, I am sent to a loading screen with suggested videos and then the entire browser crashes. It displays this warning/error message:

```
[13996:4115963444:WARNING:ffmpeg_dynamic_load_dispatch_impl.cc(168)] Unable to open shared library libavutil.so
[13996:4115963891:WARNING:ffmpeg_dynamic_load_dispatch_impl.cc(168)] Unable to open shared library libavutil.so
[13996:4115964177:WARNING:ffmpeg_dynamic_load_dispatch_impl.cc(168)] Unable to open shared library libavutil.so
[13996:4115964217:FATAL:ffmpeg_dynamic_load_audio_decoder_impl.cc(34)] Check failed: false. 
    starboard::logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage() [0x2f11b25]
    starboard::shared::ffmpeg::AudioDecoder::Create() [0x847b348]
    starboard::shared::starboard::player::filter::(anonymous namespace)::PlayerComponentsImpl::CreateAudioComponents() [0x83cce1f]
    starboard::shared::starboard::player::filter::PlayerComponents::CreateAudioRenderer() [0x838907e]
    starboard::shared::starboard::player::filter::FilterBasedPlayerWorkerHandler::Init() [0x83815e2]
    starboard::shared::starboard::player::PlayerWorker::DoInit() [0x836c55c]
    starboard::shared::starboard::player::PlayerWorker::RunLoop() [0x836bd4c]
    starboard::shared::starboard::player::PlayerWorker::ThreadEntryPoint() [0x836aac3]
    (anonymous namespace)::ThreadFunc() [0x2efb313]
    start_thread [0x7f01db7316ba]
    <unknown> [0x7f01dad4041d]

Caught signal: SIGILL (4)
    starboard::shared::signal::(anonymous namespace)::Crash() [0x2efbda3]
    <unknown> [0x7f01db73b390]
    SbSystemBreakIntoDebugger [0x2ef8009]
    <unknown> [0x2f10d9e]
    starboard::logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage() [0x2f11d01]
    starboard::shared::ffmpeg::AudioDecoder::Create() [0x847b348]
    starboard::shared::starboard::player::filter::(anonymous namespace)::PlayerComponentsImpl::CreateAudioComponents() [0x83cce1f]  starboard::shared::starboard::player::filter::PlayerComponents::CreateAudioRenderer() [0x838907e]
    starboard::shared::starboard::player::filter::FilterBasedPlayerWorkerHandler::Init() [0x83815e2]
    starboard::shared::starboard::player::PlayerWorker::DoInit() [0x836c55c]
    starboard::shared::starboard::player::PlayerWorker::RunLoop() [0x836bd4c]
    starboard::shared::starboard::player::PlayerWorker::ThreadEntryPoint() [0x836aac3]
    (anonymous namespace)::ThreadFunc() [0x2efb313]
    start_thread [0x7f01db7316ba]
    <unknown> [0x7f01dad4041d]
Illegal instruction
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the most telling failure information that you posted are the first three log lines, indicating that you don't have one of the three versions of ffmpeg that our starboard/shared code currently supports.

For more information on where the supported versions of ffmpeg are setup, see https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/993f480a798eca567dfb8088d8d0c1e712d2149c/src/starboard/shared/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.gyp#37.

As well, refer to the source of the log error messages to see how the libraries are searched: https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/993f480a798eca567dfb8088d8d0c1e712d2149c/src/starboard/shared/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_dynamic_load_dispatch_impl.cc#160.